# Lua and Objective-C: lua_pushlightuserdata() - how shall we handle the userdata object release?

Tags: objective-c, lua

The code snippet:

```
MyUIView *view = [[MyUIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)]; 
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, view);
```

I keep a reference inside Lua for the `view` object. Shall I release it from Objective-C? Does Lua retain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Lua to manage the lifetime of your object, you should use full userdata.

But, even then Lua is in plain C and does not know anything about Objective-C stuff, so it will not retain anything without your help.

Comment: Note that there are a few Lua to ObjC bridges around to help you (one of them was utterly broken when I looked a year ago — so be careful). Sorry, no links today. If you use one of them, you can post a link here to spread the word.